# How to Post a JSON and an Image to WCF (Using Content-type: application/JSON)

Tags: c#, json, image, wcf, upload

I am trying to post an Image with JSON object to wcf service in a Request.

Also i need to have Contant-Type: application/json on the request. How can i do that?

Can anyone please show me how the request will look like and also how do i receive in WCF.

Currently i am receiving like that- [image]

And sending request like-
[image]

I would like to be able to do something like that- [image]

Any suggestion or link or code would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just convert image binary data to [base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and send it as a regular field:

```
var imageBin = new byte[]{}; // need image data here
var base64Img = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBin);
var json = 
@"{ 
    'someData' : 'someValue',
    'image' : '" + base64Img + @"'
}";
```

Comment: Thanks for your email. But the request will come from iPhone. And as i mentioned before need to send a Json object and a Image. I am bit confuse as i am new to wcf and and iPhone development.

Many thanks